# How to change angular tinymce editor's localization dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-4, angular-ui-tinymce

I am using [angular-ui-tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce/) with tinymce ver 4.5.6 
I am trying to change the localization of editor dynamically. for localization I use [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) However i am not able to do it.

I try to achieve it like this

**JS**

```
var tinymce=null;
vm.tinymceOptions = {
   setup: function(editor) {
        tinymce = editor;
   },
   content_css: "vendor/tinymce/angular-ui-tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css",
   language: $translate.proposedLanguage(),
   //more options here
}

//To get localization change
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
    if(tinymce!=null)
        tinymce.execCommand('mceRepaint'); //This doesn't reflect any changes
});
```

And here is the **HTML**:

```
<form method="post" ng-show="vm.editMode">
     <textarea ui-tinymce="vm.tinymceOptions" ng-model="vm.editorContent"></textarea>
</form>
```

After refreshing the page, editor's language changes.

Comment: did you check when language changed execCommand is executed which is in $on event ?

Comment: @trd3v3lop yep, no errors, nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved it.

```
 $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
    if(tinymce!=null){
        vm.tinymceOptions.language=$translate.proposedLanguage();
        tinymce.editorManager.editors = [];
        tinymce.editorManager.createEditor("ui-tinymce-1",vm.tinymceOptions);
        tinymce.init(vm.tinymceOptions);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE does not support dynamically changing the language/localization after the editor is initialized.

You can `remove()` and `init()` the editor with different language settings but once initialized that setting cannot be changed.